# ExitCode 1603 when silently installing a .msi

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I'm trying to write a script that installs a .msi silently.  When I run the command from the Powershell command line as a ./thing.msi with the argument /qn, it works just fine.
However, now that it is in a script it is returning a 1603 error ("A fatal error occurred during install").  If I try to switch it up and go to /qb with or without /quite, it runs, but it's not silent.  Using -WindowStyle Hidden is doing nothing of note either.  Any thoughts?

```
$InsightInstall = Start-Process -FilePath $PSScriptRoot\support.msi -
ArgumentList "/quiet /qb" -Wait -Passthru -WindowStyle Hidden
if($InsightInstall.ExitCode -eq 0)
{
    Write-Host "Installation complete."
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Failed with ExitCode" $InsightInstall.ExitCode
    pause
}
```

Comment: I think you want to call msiexec: `$InsightInstall = Start-Process msiexec  -ArgumentList "/i $PSScriptRoot\support.msi /qn" -Wait -Passthru -WindowStyle Hidden`

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for the response!  Unfortunately, I have attempted that one as well.  It ends up returning the 1603 (but only when I run it from the script, when I run it straight in the command line it works just fine.)

Comment: 1603 is just generic failure code. Write a verbose log to get more error details: `-ArgumentList "/quiet /l*v logfile.txt"`. By the way `/quiet` and `qb` on the same command-line make no sense. `/quiet` is equivalent to `/qn` (see [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372024(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for the information, @zett42!  I did not know that `/quiet` and `/qn` were the same thing.  I made a verbose log file like you recommended, and it has made a very verbose log file indeed.  I'm scrolling through it now. any advice on what one should look for to expedite the process?  (I'm pretty new to Powershell and useful _useful_ scripting, so please forgive me if my questions are so simple as to being silly.)

Comment: Search for "return value 3" in the log file. The actual error cause is usually found just a few lines before that.

Comment: Zett, man, that help was invaluable.  I ended up finding out that a folder that admins have access to (which I am, of course) wasn't letting me work in it.  The script was good, a very bizarre permissions thing was not so good.  I found this out by reading the log messages above "return value 3" and googling the results.  You the man, wish I could vote up comments.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to try that hard (I don't think `Start-Process` is needed). Just run `msiexec` and specify the package, followed by parameters.

```
msiexec /i d:\path\package.msi /quiet
```

Comment: Hey Bill, thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, unless I'm misunderstanding something, that's only a command that works in the command line.  I need to use -PassThru to store it into an object so that I can monitor the ExitCodes.  Just running it like that doesn't allow me to do that (not in a way that I'm aware of, anyway.)

Comment: Have you actually tried it? PowerShell will put the exit code in the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable when `msiexec.exe` completes.

Comment: I wouldn't have said it didn't work if I hadn't (that would just be a waste of everyone's time).  I tried it again with the $LASTEXITCODE variable.  When it exits, the variable is empty, so it's not doing anything.  The install fails, but I don't get any red error message when I type it in.  I also tried using Invoke-Command on it, but that ended up spitting our red text.  "Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters."

Comment: The `msiexec.exe` exit codes are documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376931.aspx).

Comment: Bill, it turned out to be a very bizarre permissions issue where a folder that admins have access to (which I of course am) was one that I didn't have access to.  The code is fine and it runs.  Thanks for your help on this issue (wish I could vote up comments).